# How to convert ajax data into array of objects

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object

have an ajax call which returns array of objects like this:

[image]

I am not able to convert this array of objects into array of arrays data in integer.

My Ajax call code is:

```
var bookedSeats = [];
        let  myArray = [];
 $.ajax({
            url: 'public/get-show_booked-table.php',
            type: "post",
            data: 'show_id=' + showId
                    + '&ticket_class_id=' + cleassId
                    + '&schedule_id=' + schedule_id
                    + '&organizer_id=' + org_id
                    + '&booking_date=' + show_booking_date,
            success: function (result) {
                 myArray = result;
                 bookedSeats = myArray.split(",");
                 console.log(bookedSeats);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(xhr);
            }
        });
```

Comment: you can just convert them to number 
`myArray.split(",").map(e => parseInt(e))`

Comment: It's an array of numeric strings, not of objects. In most cases PHP has no problem converting strings like these to numbers, so you can use them as if they are numbers, no conversion needed. That being say, and assuming you're going to try to correct it anyway, instead of correcting this array afterwards, it is much better to send the correct array in the first place.

Comment: myArray.split(",").map(e => parseInt(e))

now solve my problem thank you  
Ravikumar

Comment: What are you sending from server? Why don't you create an array of integers on the server directly and return it to the client thus avoiding further conversions?

Comment: Why are users providing resolving advice as comments?  This is not how the Stack Overflow Q&A is designed to work.  Does this question need clarifications?  If so, why are there no close votes on this question.